# Is there a way to make VBA Power query refresh faster?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I have this macro that can successfully Open a workbook and refresh every Power Query connection in it. If I manually click the "Refresh All", the whole process takes 3 - 5 mins. But if I run the macro, it takes up to an hour to complete the process.

I have tried using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` but there was no impact. Is there any way to make the refresh faster?

```
Dim fname As String
    Dim owb As Workbook
    Dim Cname As String
    Dim objConnection As WorkbookConnection, bBackground As Boolean
    fname = "PowerQuery04-CSVMultipleFileImport.xlsx"
    Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath & "\" & fname)
        For Each objConnection In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
            If Left(objConnection.Name, 8) = "Query - " Then
            Cname = objConnection.Name
                With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(Cname).OLEDBConnection
                    .BackgroundQuery = False  'or true, up to you
                    .Refresh
                End With
            End If
        Next
    'owb.RefreshAll
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:02:00"))
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    owb.Save
    owb.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: How about `.BackgroundQuery = True`?

Comment: That's also slow!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll get better performance if you use the [Workbook.RefreshAll method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.refreshall) rather than looping through queries.

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```